# How I can install broadcom 4311 wireless?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

No puedo conectarme a través de wifi de mi HP. Creo que ubuntu no reconoce la tarjeta Broadcom 4311

```
                            Translation via Google Translate
```

I can't connect via Wi-Fi on my HP. I think Ubuntu doesn't recognize the Broadcom 4311

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install the propietary driver. Use the dash to find the "Controladores adicionales" program (I see that you speak in spanish). There you may have the option to activate the needed driver.

It is possible that you need to connect to Internet previously using the Ethernet device, to download the driver.

*In spanish (en español):*

A lo mejor necesitás instalar el correspondiente driver propietario. Para eso, usando el dash de Unity buscá el programa llamado "Controladores adicionales". Si tenés suerte, allí mismo te aparecerá la opción para activar el driver propietario.

Es posible que necesites previamente estar conectado a Internet, para que pueda descargarse el driver. Para eso, conectate por cable (placa Ethernet).

Saludos. (Regards.)

Ariel

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in a Acer Extensa 5620Z with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed, and finally I have found the solution in this forum (in spanish): [[Solución] Problemas con el wifi Broadcom BCM4311](http://www.portalubuntu.com/2011/11/solucion-problemas-con-el-wifi-broadcom.html)

Here I translate the conclusion:

> The solution is to uninstall the driver and install a package that downloads and installs a driver that works correctly:

```
 sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

 sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

And restart the computer to load drivers at startup.

I hope that it works on your computers.